# How to display a list from database in flutter

Tags: flutter

I am a beginner in flutter, I want to retrieve a list of announcements from the database and display it in a listView but I have a compilation error under `snapshot.data` saying that `A value of type 'List<Annonce>?' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'List<Annonce>'. Try changing the type of the variable, or casting the right-hand type to 'List<Annonce>'.`

The code is :

````
                   future: AnnonceDataBase.instance.annonces(),
                   builder: (BuildContext context,
                       AsyncSnapshot<List<Annonce>> snapshot) {
                     if (snapshot.hasData) {
                       List<Annonce> annonces = snapshot.data;
                       return ListView.separated(... ```
````

Answer (score 0):

Change like this:

````
future: AnnonceDataBase.instance.annonces(),
                   builder: (BuildContext context,
                       AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
                     if (snapshot.hasData) {
                       List<Annonce> annonces = snapshot.data! as List<Annonce>;
                       return ListView.separated(... ```
````

Oh, by the way, Please consider to vote up and give it as accepted answer if an answer solves your problem. The reason is that other people with same issue can easily find the right answer easily. Have fun!